# Scoping of variables

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I debug the following code and for some reason despite the fact the items do added to the returnDC list, the returnDC list is always empty.
It might be a scoping issue, but I"m not sure.

```
class _MyGridState extends State<MyGrid> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(columns: getDataColumnTest(), rows: [
      DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(Text('sdf')),
        DataCell(Text('sdf')),
      ]),

    ]);
  }
Future List<DataColumn> getDataColumnTest() async {
    dbutils db = dbutils();
    List<DataColumn> returnDC = List<DataColumn>();

    AuthResult results = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: 'XXX@gmail.com', password: 'WOWOW');
    DocumentSnapshot ds = await Firestore.instance.document(
        'Settings' + '/' + 'hey').get();
    ds.data.map((f, d) {
      DataColumn dc =
      DataColumn(label: Text(f.toString()), tooltip: d.toString());
      returnDC.add(dc);
    });

    return returnDC;
  }
```

Any assistant will be highly appreciated
Asi

Comment: async-await or use callback, since api is async in nature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Future<List<DataColumn>> getDataColumnTest() async{

    dbutils db = dbutils();
    List<DataColumn> returnDC = List<DataColumn>();

    AuthResult results = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: 'XXX@gmail.com', password: 'WOWOW');
      DocumentSnapshot ds = await Firestore.instance.document('Settings' + '/' + 'hey').get();
        ds.data.map((f, d) {
          DataColumn dc =
              DataColumn(label: Text(f.toString()), tooltip: d.toString());
          returnDC.add(dc);
        });
      });
    });
    return returnDC;
  }
```

The api is asynchronous, therefore you need to use `async` and `await` to wait for the data to be retrieved and then you can return the list.

---

Since this is inside the `build` method then you can use `FutureBuilder`:

```
            FutureBuilder(
              future:
                  getDataColumnTest(), 
             builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DataColumn> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data);
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                }

                // By default, show a loading spinner.
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            )
```

Comment: Peter: in this case return type must be Future and even if I add the Future keyword I receive and compiler error "Method must have an explicit list of parameters". BTW I"m not sure that using Future will be valid because I"m calling this method from Widget (but I might be wrong), I modified the question according to your solution

Comment: Ur right it must be `Future<List<DataColumn>>` if you are calling this in the build method then I advice to use the `FutureBuilder`

Comment: So this should return a `Future` then in the widget `FutureBuilder` it has a property called `future` which you can give it this function as a value

Comment: Can you please modify it with the FutureBuilder?

Comment: @AsiB check the edit something like that should work, ofcourse the `Text` widget you can remove it and use something else because `snapshot.data` probably doesnt return a String

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#5-display-the-data

Comment: @AsiB If the answer helped you, please mark it as correct and upvote it thank you!